# Error when using FirebaseStorageUI + SDWebImage

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-storage, sdwebimage

I've been trying to solve this problem for hours and nothing seems to work.

I want to display images on uitableviewcell using FirebaseStorageUI and SDWebImage. I used [this](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/ios/download-files) tutorial as a reference (see "Downloading Images with FirebaseUI" section on that website).

Here's what my code looks like on tableview willDisplay cell:

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, willDisplay cell: UITableViewCell, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    let cell = cell as! CategoryCell
    let title = categoriesData[indexPath.row].name

    let refTest = FIRStorage().reference().child("images/categories/testImage.jpg")
    cell.bgImageView.sd_setImage(with: refTest, placeholderImage: #imageLiteral(resourceName: "placeholderImg")) {(image, error, cacheType, storageRef) in
        if let error = error {
            print("error downloading image: \(error)")
        }
    }
    cell.bgImageView.alpha = 0.5
    cell.titleLabel.text = title
}
```

And here's the error message:

> error downloading image: Error Domain=FIRStorageErrorDomain
>   Code=-13040 "User cancelled the upload/download."
>   UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=User cancelled the upload/download.}

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: does it work without sdwebimage?

Comment: Did you scroll the tableView when the images was being downloaded ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `.storage()` after `FIRStorage`.

Should be like:

```
let refTest = FIRStorage.storage().reference().child("images/categories/testImage.jpg")
```